# Change figure caption name in "thesis" document

Tags: macros, floats, captions

Does anyone have an idea why this approach to changing figure naming doesn't work in *thesis* type document? I'm using babel and all other captions translate normally, except "Figure", which stays at "Fig." no matter what I do. I've tried to change it using *renewcommand* macro but it does not work:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{thesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}

\addto\captionsslovene{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Slika}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{picture.png}
\caption{Random caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I switch to *book* document type it works as expected, but I would really like to keep this document in the *thesis* format to make use of all the good stuff that enables me to format my work properly.

Comment: And of course, I found the answer 5 minutes after posting the question here (even though I spent 4 hours searching for it before posting the question here).

The thesis uses "figureshortname" for captioning figures, so substituting "figurename" for the latter in the "renewcommand" line solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redefining `\figureshortname` instead of or in addition to `\figurename`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{thesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}

\addto\captionsslovene{\renewcommand{\figureshortname}{Slika}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
%\includegraphics[scale=1]{picture.png}
\caption{Random caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```